# Online contact form | Send email message using php | HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: php, forms, http-status-code-405

I am trying to submit an online contact form by using PHP but I get error message *"HTTP ERROR 405"* in submission.

Hello everyone!

I am trying to setup an Online Contact Form by using PHP. You can see the code here:

`https://codepen.io/p_demetriou/pen/mdjRvJz`

Below you can see the code of PHP file send-email.php :

```
<?php
  // Get the form data
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $surname = $_POST['surname'];
  $company = $_POST['company'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  // Set the recipient email address
  $to = "contactvenusproperties@gmail.com";
  // $to = 'recipient@example.com';

  // Set the email subject
  $subject = 'Venus Holdings | New Message from Online Contact Form';

  // Build the email content
  $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
  $email_content = "Surname: $surname\n";
  $email_content = "Company: $company\n";
  $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
  $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

  // Build the email headers
  $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

  // Send the email
  mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);
?>
```

When i submit the form, i get the following error message:

*This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.

HTTP ERROR 405*

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: 405 is "method not allowed" - does your host allow POST requests? Does your mail server allow you to send emails "from" any old email address, regardless of whether it's configured for that domain?

Comment: Where's the Javascript or html reference here?

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: `$email_content = ...` will overwrite `$email_content` in the `Surname` and `Company` lines

Comment: @dimitriupe please check the documentation [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In above code pls mention the proper path of  send-mail.php file. Right now it's not proper that's why it's throwing you the error of `405  Method not allowed`.

Comment: @droopsnoot the html, css and javascript coding can be found here: [link](https://codepen.io/p_demetriou/pen/mdjRvJz) . Also the recipient email address is under ...@gmail.com

Comment: @BhattAkshay the send-email.php file is in the same directory as the html, css and js files.

Comment: @brombeer Why it will overwrite? How should I amend the code in order to avoid overwriting? Thanks!

Comment: `$email_content .= ...` will append, `$email_content = ...` will overwrite

Comment: @brombeer I changed the coding for Surname and Company to the below: `$email_content .= "Surname: $surname\n";
  $email_content .= "Company: $company\n";`      Is this correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?" - does it produce the correct result when you debug it? If so, then it is correct.

Comment: @BhattAkshay yes all files are in the same directory